# Is 'He reflected himself in the mirror' a correct sentence?

Tags: sentence-meaning, grammaticality

> He reflected himself in the mirror.

I wrote this myself.
Can you explain what this sentence means?
Is this correct or incorrect?

Answer (score 1):

It's probably clear what it is supposed to mean, but it is not grammatically correct. The subject of [reflect](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/reflect) must be either be a beam of light or the reflective object (in this case the mirror), for example:

> The mirror reflected his image.

You could make this into passive voice so that his image moves to the front of the sentence, and then he can see the image.

> He saw his image reflected in the mirror.
>   He saw himself reflected in the mirror.

This uses passive voice.

Comment: The sentence is not necessarily ungrammatical.

Comment: @Clare, can you describe a situation in which it would be grammatical?

Comment: @JavaLatte Would you accept: *Carefully arranging the cut-out of himself at the exact angle, he reflected himself in the mirror.*

Comment: @RonaldSole: neat, understandable, but he (the subject of reflect) is still not a reflective surface or a beam of light.

Comment: @RonaldSole: Lose the mirror and add the word **on** and it would work: "he reflected **on** himself". Meaning 2 https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/reflect. His mind becomes he mirror.

Comment: @Ronald and Java: by a combination of metaphor and, what is it, synecdoche?: "We stood side by side in front of the mirror, that is, we stood side by side in the mirror. And I looked into his eyes, and his eyes reflected my image in the mirror. But he became so full of himself, he no longer reflected my eyes in the mirror; he reflected himself in the mirror."

Comment: Or, simply, *He reflected himself in the mirror*, with *he* standing for *his eyes*. @Ronald et al.

Comment: @Clare, if you read this sentence for the first time, would you interpret it in that way?

Comment: That's approximately how I read it, yes.

Comment: @Clare, You have a weird mind.